# how to create/delete AWS lambda from rest-api?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm not familiar with AWS lambdas.

Does AWS provide swagger or anything similar to lambdas?

my use case doesn't require me to create rest endpoint to the lambdas. do I also need to play around with gateways as well?

- I'm not looking for cli solutions: sam/aws-cli/serverless/...

Comment: Swagger and Lambda are two different things. Can you please explain more detail - what kind of REST API you are looking for?

Comment: [This](https://github.com/nsriram/lambda-the-terraform-way)  might cover both(aws lambda + api gateway for rest api). Plus as pointed out both lambda and rest api(api gateway + http api) are different things.

Comment: I'm looking for official AWS POST/DELETE REST APIs to create and delete lambdas. for example: curl -XPOST aws.com/add-lambda ...

Comment: Is there anything stopping you from using the official AWS SDKs or CLIs? They're built for that use case. Otherwise you'll need to implement request signing etc. yourself to talk to the APIs directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything in AWS uses the same public API that AWS provides. How that's implemented depends on the service. The official SDKs/CLIs use that same API and abstract the implementation details for you, so I'd recommend sticking to those.

If you want to build your own tool to talk to the AWS APIs or more specifically Lambda, you can have a look at the official developer guide, which includes an [API-Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_Reference.html).

More specifically you're going to need these two actions:

- [CreateFunction](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_CreateFunction.html)
- [DeleteFunction](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_DeleteFunction.html)

You should be aware, that you need to implement the [Signature v4 process](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html) to sign your requests with your AWS credentials yourself in that case, which is non-trivial. This signing process is used to authenticate yourself to AWS or more specifically to Identity and Access Management.

The API-Reference doesn't directly list the API-endpoints, but you're going to have to use the one for lambda in the region you want to create/delete your functions in, e.g. `https://lambda.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com`, where `eu-central-1` would be your region. For a full list of the service endpoints for Lambda take a look at [this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/lambda-service.html).

**I'd really recommend you stick to one of the official SDKs/CLIs - this will make your life much easier.**